# How to tell if the next line should be indented when parsing python

Tags: python, indentation

I am writing a simple templating engine in python, and it involves mixing python with other languages, and I need to determine the indentation level of any given line of python code.

I was wondering if it's accurate to say that a new indentation level is always indicated by a colon (:) at the end of the line.

Here's a line of python:

```
if my_boolean:
```

Since there is a colon at the end of this line, I would determine that the next line of python should be an indented block. Is this always accurate? Are there cases when I need to indent when a colon is not present?

Comment: In general, yes.  A colon at the end of a line indicates that you are beginning a new block of code that should be indented.

Comment: No, `(lambda x:<linebreak>...)` doesn't have any indentation implications. Do you really need to handle this yourself? You may be able to use Python's own parser with `ast.parse`.

Comment: @user2357112 I will look into ast.parse tomorrow.  Thanks for replying so fast.

Comment: What about optional and arbitrary indentation of parenthesized, braced or bracketed expressions?

Comment: not just indent needs tracking.  level i.e. ‘:’ on line 1 then 2 space indent next line implies line 3 also needs a 2 space indent.  or 0 indent to out of the indent scope.  the housekeeping could be brutal, so i’d try to use builtin parsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A colon at the end of the line is the most prevalent example of an indicator that the following line is indented. The other one is any line that has more opening parentheses, braces, or brackets than closing ones. The latter case is more complicated because the order of the brackets matters very much, and also because the following indentation is arbitrary.

Another thing to consider is that you don't have any indication that wether a given line is expected to be *un*indented until you get to it.

The moral of the story is that you're better off using the existing machinery exposed by the `ast` module rather than reinventing the wheel. It's an awfully complicated wheel sometimes.

Comment: I was running some tests, and it seems to me that indentation after an unclosed bracket/brace/paren is totally optional.  I'm using python3.6

Comment: @Carsen. You are absolutely correct. An open brace means that an indentation *may* follow. A colon means it *will* follow, and anything else means it will not.